# how to create 3d triangle with 3 point using matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a 3D plot like this: it's from an equations. but I don't have any idea again for making this, I've tried sereval times, but the result just a dot, as you can see on the result image. Sorry for my bad english.
Here is the expectation result:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
from matplotlib import style

plt.figure('SPLTV',figsize=(10,5))
custom=plt.subplot(121,projection='3d')
#x-2y+z=6
x1=np.array([1,-2,1])
y1=np.array([5,3,7])
z1=np.array([6])
custom.scatter(x1,y1,z1)
custom.set_xlabel('X')
custom.set_ylabel('Y')
custom.set_zlabel('Z')
plt.show()
```

Here's my result :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is `Poly3DCollection`. Consider the following modification of your code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection  # appropriate import to draw 3d polygons
from matplotlib import style

plt.figure('SPLTV',figsize=(10,5))
custom=plt.subplot(121,projection='3d')
#x-2y+z=6
x1=np.array([1, -2, 1])
y1=np.array([5, 3, 7])
z1=np.array([0, 0, 6])  # z1 should have 3 coordinates, right?
custom.scatter(x1,y1,z1)

# 1. create vertices from points
verts = [list(zip(x1, y1, z1))]
# 2. create 3d polygons and specify parameters
srf = Poly3DCollection(verts, alpha=.25, facecolor='#800000')
# 3. add polygon to the figure (current axes)
plt.gca().add_collection3d(srf)

custom.set_xlabel('X')
custom.set_ylabel('Y')
custom.set_zlabel('Z')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I'll try using poly3dcollection